# Draggable and click to front

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, z-index, draggable

I'm using Jquery & JqueryUI to make some elements on a site draggable, I want them to come to front when clicked, but I'm having issues – draggable works fine, but every element (.flower) just stays in the order it was originally.

```
 // jquery


$(function() {
  $( ".flower" ).draggable();
});


var zmax = 0;
$( '.flower' ).click( function () {
  $( this ).siblings( '.flower' ).each(function() {
    var cur = $( this ).css( 'z-index');
    zmax = cur > zmax ? $( this ).css( 'z-index') : zmax;
  });
$( this ).css( 'z-index', zmax+1 );
});


//html

<div id="flower1" class="flower"><img src="images/flowers/f1.png"></img></div>
<div id="flower2" class="flower"><img src="images/flowers/f2.png"></img></div>
<div id="flower3" class="flower"><img src="images/flowers/f3.png"></img></div>


//css

.flower {
    position: fixed;
     z-index: 0;
     left: 10px;
     top: 10px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you want achieve exactly?. checking your code, you always click the top image unless they are of different sizes and the ones that is clicked bubbles up

Comment: I have draggable images, which works fine, but I want the one you have clicked on to be on top (z-index). You can always click on an image because it's not completely covered, but it doesn't come to top.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. Try to rearrange your code like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".flower").draggable();
    $('.flower').click(function () {
        var zmax = 0;
        $(this).siblings('.flower').each(function () {
            var cur = $(this).css('z-index');
            zmax = cur > zmax ? $(this).css('z-index') : zmax;
        });
        $(this).css('z-index', Number(zmax) + 1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, just tried this, and it's still not working. Have tried in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, and have double checked I have loaded jQuery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you applied the Number() function?

Answer (score 0):

The .click() event was somehow having problems with the .draggable – had to click and hold for the code to run and bring the element to top.

replaced .click() with .mousedown() and that fixed the problem.